# 'Non-conformable arguments' in R code

Tags: r, function, arguments, least-squares

: )  I previously wrote an R function that will compute a least-squares polynomial of arbitrary order to fit whatever data I put into it. "LeastSquaresDegreeN.R"  The code works because I can reproduce results I got previously.  However, when I try to put new data into it I get a "Non-conformable arguments" error.

```
"Error in Conj(t(Q))%*%t(b) : non-conformable arguments"
```

An extremely simple example of data that should work:

```
t <- seq(1,100,1)
fifthDegree <- t^5
LeastSquaresDegreeN(t,fifthDegree,5)
```

This *should* output and plot a polynomial f(t) = t^5 (up to rounding errors).
However I get "Non-conformable arguments" error even if I explicitly make these vectors:

```
t <- as.vector(t)
fifthDegree <- as.vector(fifthDegree)
LeastSquaresDegreeN(t,fifthDegree,5)
```

I've tried putting in the transpose of these vectors too - but nothing works.

Surely the solution is really simple.  Help!?  Thank you!

Here's the function:

```
LeastSquaresDegreeN <- function(t, b, deg)
{
# Usage:  t is independent variable vector, b is function data
# i.e., b = f(t) 
# deg is desired polynomial order
# deg <- deg + 1 is a little adjustment to make the R loops index correctly. 
deg <- deg + 1
t <- t(t)
dataSize <- length(b)
A <- mat.or.vec(dataSize, deg)  # Built-in R function to create zero 
# matrix or zero vector of arbitrary size
# Given basis phi(z) = 1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + ... 
# Define matrix A
for (i in 0:deg-1) {
    A[1:dataSize,i+1] = t^i
}
# Compute QR decomposition of A.  Pull Q and R out of QRdecomp
QRdecomp <- qr(A)
Q <- qr.Q(QRdecomp, complete=TRUE)
R <- qr.R(QRdecomp, complete=TRUE)
# Perform Q^* b^T  (Conjugate transpose of Q)
c <- Conj(t(Q))%*%t(b)
# Find x.  R isn't square - so we have to use qr.solve
x <- qr.solve(R, c) 
# Create xPlot (which is general enough to plot any degree 
# polynomial output)
xPlot = x[1,1]
for (i in 1:deg-1){
    xPlot = xPlot + x[i+1,1]*t^i
}
# Now plot it.  Least squares "l" plot first, then the points in red.
plot(t, xPlot, type='l', xlab="independent variable t", ylab="function values f(t)", main="Data Plotted with Nth Degree Least Squares Polynomial", col="blue")
points(t, b, col="red")
} # End
```

Comment: The error is occurring in the line `c <- Conj(t(Q))%*%t(b)`. I'm unsure why you transpose `b`, since it's a vector, and the computation seems to work without the transpose. Also, it's not a good idea to use `t` as a variable name, since it you also use it as a function.

Comment: c should be a vector rather than a matrix...  I will take a closer look at my programming to find some better form.  Using "t" was not a good choice!  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: For some reason when I restarted R I could get this to work if I transposed the second vector.  I swear I tried this multiple times with a bunch of different vector sets.  Is it possible that I just accidentally found a bug or flaw?